# why is the below query not executing properly without alias name?

Tags: mysql

Below is the question asked in hackerrank :
Write a query to find the node type of BST ordered by the value of the node. Output one of the following for each node:

Root: If node is root node.
Leaf: If node is leaf node.
Inner: If node is neither root nor leaf node

table is as follows:

```
N P
1 2
3 2
6 8 
9 8
2 5
5 NULL
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT IS :

```
1 Leaf
2 Inner
3 Leaf
5 Root
6 Leaf
8 Inner
9 Leaf
```

query which i used to solve this was :

```
SELECT N, 
       IF(P IS NULL,'Root',IF((SELECT COUNT(P) 
                               FROM BST 
                               WHERE P=B.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf')) 
FROM   BST AS B 
ORDER  BY N;
```

and this gives me the desired output but if i use the below query it does not..

```
SELECT N,
       IF(P IS NULL,'Root',IF((SELECT COUNT(P) 
                               FROM BST 
                               WHERE P=BST.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf')) 
FROM   BST 
ORDER  BY N;
```

Can somebody explain me the reason behind it , the change over here that i have made is just replacing the alias name with the name of the table itself, then why is it not giving the desired output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in second case the WHERE condition works for internal BST table.

You also can try this query -

```
SELECT
 b1.N, IF(b1.P IS NULL, 'Root', IF(COUNT(b2.P) > 0,'Inner','Leaf'))
FROM BST b1
  LEFT JOIN BST b2 ON b1.N = b2.P
GROUP BY b1.N
```

Comment: could you please elaborate because i am unable to understand this part properly, or could you provide me link from which i can learn more about it?

Comment: @deb He means that using an alias triggers a correlated subquery because it fetches the external table.

Comment: Understood :) Thanks for your responses (y)